# drawing a paraboloid usings tikz with xyz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my first time working with `tikz` and I feel like I've taken on a project that is too difficult for a first timer.

I am trying to recreate a picture like the following:

[image]

but I can't seem to get the paraboloid working. I also don't know how to do the curved line for `$W^s$`.

Lastly, instead of having `E^c` as a bracket, I'd just like to shade in the xy plane.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,z=0.35cm,>=stealth]
% The axes
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=-13.5) -- (xyz cs:x=13.5) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=-13.5) -- (xyz cs:y=13.5) node[right] {$z$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=-13.5) -- (xyz cs:z=13.5) node[above] {$y$};

% The thick ticks
\foreach \coo in {-10,-5,5,10}
{
  \draw[thick] (\coo,-3pt) -- (\coo,3pt) node[below=6pt] {\coo};
  \draw[thick] (-3pt,\coo) -- (3pt,\coo) node[left=6pt] {\coo};
  \draw[thick] (xyz cs:y=-0.3pt,z=\coo) -- (xyz cs:y=0.3pt,z=\coo) node[below=8pt] {\coo};
}
% Dashed lines for the points P, Q
\draw[dashed] 
  (xyz cs:z=-5) -- +(7,0) coordinate (u)
  %--  (xyz cs:y=7) --  +(-5,0) --  ++(xyz cs:x=-5,z=-5) coordinate (v) ;
  --  (xyz cs:x=7);
  %-- +(0,-7) coordinate (w) --
  %cycle;

\node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label={below:$x_1$}] at (u) {};
% The origin
%\node[align=center] at (3,-3) (ori) {(0,0,0)\\\text{origin}};
%\draw[->,help lines,shorten >=3pt] (ori) .. controls (1,-2) and (1.2,-1.5) .. (0,0,0);     

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the lower curved line of the parabolid you could try "control", have a look at the example in the  documentation.

Comment: You can draw the ellipse then the parabol in 2D to get the paraboloid.